# Use php crypt or Mysql enryption functions for field encryption?

Tags: php, mysql, encryption

CodeIgniter application that needs to be able to encrypt/decrypt spefici fields and for specific records.

I am thinking of two posible ways to do this:

1. Use the crypt() php function and pass the result to the SQL statement
2. Use the MySql encryption functions

Which one should i choose and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the option that allows the best forward-compatibility.

If in the future you no longer use a MySQL Database your cryptography will become inoperable.

Almost all major program languages support some form of **[mcrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php)**  that you will be able to port should you need to move the code away from php to something else.

Again, think forward compatibility as you develop your code.

Comment: Good point about db independancy, but why not then use crypt() php function? If i need to change form PHP to something else, i think i will have much bigger issues than crypt..yes?

Comment: I thought the point I made was that using a cryptographic was the best option. If I failed to make that the point of my answer, my apologies. Further, crypt() will not meet your needs, you will have to use something along the lines of mcrypt() as it is a two-way algorithm whereas crypt() is a one way algorithm.